# Should i use SwingUtilities.invokeLater() inside of SwingWorker.doInBackground()?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker, event-dispatch-thread, invokelater

The common way to interact with EDT from swing worker is useing get() method. But i have a long task and code like this:

```
public Void doInBackground() {
    for(Object o : objects) {
         doSomething();
         MyGlobalGUIConsole.addMessage("Done for " + o);
    }
}
```

In most tutotials is recommended to use return values to get something back from SwingWorker to EDT, but can i just:

```
public Void doInBackground() {
    for(Object o : objects) {
        doSomething();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {        
            @Override                                      
            public void run() {                            
                MyGlobalGUIConsole.addMessage("Done for " + o);
            }                                              
        });                                                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can, but the SwingWorker has methods designed to report progress of a background task: you call `publish()` from `doInBackground()` to publish progress, and you override `process()` (which is called in the EDT) in order to display the progress. So the above code could be rewritten as:

```
public Void doInBackground() {
    for(Object o : objects) {
        doSomething();
        publish("Done for " + o);                           
    }                                             
}

@Override
protected void process(List<String> messages) {
    for (String message : messages) {
        MyGlobalGUIConsole.addMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: @AvrDragon usage of invokeLater in the SwingWorker is wrong concept, is about wrapping contents from MyGlobalGUIConsole.addMessage() to the invokerLater(), not in the SwingWorker, because process() could be notified EDT properly